# How to get sum of two columns multiplication

Tags: c#, datatable

I have a datatable in which there are two column named col1 and col2. I want to get sum of (col1 * col2) of each row.
i am using following code..

```
object sumObject;
sumObject = dt.Compute("Sum(col1* col2)", "(id = '" + id+ "') ");
```

But it doesn't worked. It produces an error as :

```
Syntax error in aggregate argument: Expecting a single column argument with possible 'Child' qualifier.
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

A more readable way is using `LINQ-To-DataSet`:

```
int sumTotal = dt.AsEnumerable()
    .Where(r => r.Field<int>("id") == id)
    .Sum(r => r.Field<int>("col1") * r.Field<int>("col2") );
```

Comment: i want achieve this using compute method is it possible??

Comment: @social: maybe it's possible, but it won't be readable, maintainable and you will never remember how it works or why it doesn't work. I don't like fiddling around with strings and objects instead of using strongly typed methods. LINQ is much more poerful than the old expression syntax. Note that i've added the filter for the id.

Answer (score 1):

```
double dTotal = 0.0;
foreach (DataRow dr in dt.Rows) 
{
   double dValue1, dValue2;

   if (!double.TryParse(dr["col1"].ToString(), out dValue1))
   {
       //error parsing
       break;
   }
   if (!double.TryParse(dr["col2"].ToString(), out dValue2))
   {
       //error parsing
       break;
   }
   dTotal += dValue1 * dValue2;
}
```